# Use CEF offline without appcache

Tags: chromium-embedded, html5-appcache, electron, offlineapps

I'm investigating using [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) in a new desktop application in which I want to render the UI with HTML5/js. However, I don't want the model to be a typical web application that's just rendered in an embedded browser (i.e. fetching resources from a remote server like a web page). Basically I want to have a desktop app that comes prepackaged with all the HTML and scripts that are needed to render the UI, and function entirely offline.

My question is: Is CEF capable of doing this more or less out of the box? Or will I need to write a bunch of custom code for handling and rendering local resources, or embedding a local web server? A simple example would be building the UI buttons and output for a basic calculator app (although the planned application is much more complex). How would I begin to approach this?

I'm also looking at [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) as a possible solution. It seems like it is more geared towards what I want to do (render a UI with web technologies but without necessarily being connected to anything). However, we have some legacy c++ libraries that we need to integrate and I believe this would be easier with CEF than with Electron.

From looking around, it seems that CEF supports appcache for so-called "offline apps". However, I'm leery of using it because of the [numerous problems](http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag) it has. Also it seems like [appcache is dying](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-US/docs/2015/application-cache-api-has-been-deprecated/), so I'd rather not tie myself to that sinking ship anyways. Unfortunately [service worker](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/) doesn't quite look ready for primetime either.

Comment: It's possible. Either you can use a custom scheme factory and supply the resources yourself (basically map a some kind of rc://100 to a 100.html file), or load the HTMLs and supply them in-memory.

Answer (score 2):

See the `CEF General Usage` guide under `Request Handling` for the two supported methods of dealing with custom requests.

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage.md#markdown-header-request-handling

What your looking for is indeed possible out of the box and relatively easy to implement. The `cefclient` example application has working examples.

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/694b45717c971a0bb639f555b640d313fc15ccc8/tests/cefclient/?at=master